# Pass password to excel file using vb script

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, ssis

i have a excel file it is password enabled in a script task i am reading the file using Vb

I am not able to pass the password so that it allows me to read from the file.

How can i do it.Where can i pass the password. I also tried using FileInfo class there is no option for that.

present script is:

```
    Dim fs As FileStream
    Dim sr As StreamReader
    Dim line As String
    fs = File.OpenRead(Dts.Variables("File_Name").Value)
    sr = File.OpenText(Dts.Variables("File_Name").Value)
   'Read first line of the file
    line = sr.ReadLine
    Dim str As String
    str = line
     sr.Close()
    fs.Close()
```

It works if the file is not password enabled.Any help. Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the actual [Excel COM Object Model.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

There is a property of the Workbook class that allows you to set the password.

Comment: @Ich - happy to hear it.  You can do a lot of cool stuff with that model as well.